# Ultra road machine or a CX/gravel bike to replace/augment my MTB?

Tags: road-bike, gravel

I currently own a flat bar, hardtail 29er MTB.
I can pretty much ride it anywhere.
The thing is I usually ride on tarmac anyway with some gravel segments if I take a shortcut through the woods.
Where I live is very flat, not many hills etc. Most of routes are paved, there's some gravel/dirt roads. I quite like riding off road as there's no car traffic, but a lot of my riding is b roads with asphalt anyway.
As a result I'd tried a proper road bike and I'm pretty convinced that I want to ride something with drop bars.
Eventually I want to ride 100+ kms on weekend days - I've actually done it already and it wasn't too strenuous.

My dilemma is whether I should get a proper tarmac race machine with aero features, tubeless clinchers, aero spokes etc and keep my MTB for everyday rides or should I replace my MTB with one size fits all gravel or CX bike (I might get two sets of wheels perhaps).

If I replace my MTB, I have a higher budget, the bike is more versatile, gravel bikes have hooks for bikepacking and wider tyres, it also probably means I have budget for disc brakes.
The only reason I don't want to go that route is that gravel bikes are rapidly evolving - for example 2019 Trek bikes have a form of rear 'suspension' (ISOSpeed?) but no such feature on the front, so lots of current gravel bikes feel like a work a in progress and next years models are bound to be better.
On the other hand endurance type road bikes are pretty mature and IMO you get better components in a given price range.
My typical routine is 2-4 hours riding on weekdays with occasional all day riding on weekends. At the moment I am pretty serious about my cycling hoppy and want to reward myself with nice hardware.

Comment: It seems you know all the arguments and are well informed about the tech. It sounds also like you already decided and now look for arguments to support/dissuade you. That's not ideal for SE question format. Have a look at the [tour]. Perhaps our chat will help you better since it is less constraint by format: [link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome)

Comment: Effectively you have two questions. "My budget is one really nice bike or two average bikes, whats best?" and  "Are gravel bike changing so fast that I am better putting off purchasing one for a year or two"

Comment: I think the CX bike is the odd one out in your list. Often gravel and endurance bikes have a lot in common. CX bikes however have three distinct features that may not be desirable to you: (i) high top tube to allow to shoulder the bike, (ii) aggressive geometry with nervous steering, very unlike todays MTB, and (iii) little bottom bracket drop to pedal through corners.

Comment: Swapping wheel sets on disc brake bikes might involve having to re-centre the brake calipers every time. It might very well be that you don't bother with all the hassle after a while and run with one set all the time. If you do not need knobby tyres, there might be no need whatsoever. Some good wide tyres roll as fast as narrow tyres on most surfaces you find out there. There's an aerodynamic malus though. I'm pretty happy with 35-622 G-Ones on road, gravel and dry trails, for instance.

Comment: @gschenk thank you - exactly the experience I am looking for - ideally I'd like to keep one bike for minimalists reasons and I agree swapping wheels all the time is not too fun. one set of slightly wider tyres might suit me just fine - I'm not about to beat any world records anyway...

Comment: Just get an allroad or rando bike, 650Bx42 tires or thereabouts. That's the genre that does everything you want perfectly. Gravel and CX bikes tend to be slanted towards more aggressive geometry than you probably need or want.

Comment: I quite liked the geometry on the road bike that I tested, I probably also don't need the rando massive hauling capabilities - I will do shorter rides most of the time and even on the longer rides, there's plenty of shops and civilisation in between - I'd rather carry less on me and have to call backup ever now and then rather than haul extra kilos with me (I have more than enough of my own)

Comment: My rides are similar to what you described. 80% of times on tarmac either commuting or 50-100 mile rides and 20% riding or bikepacking gravel roads or smooth single tracks. I found a 700x35 gravel tire good enough for providing traction and comfort needed. So I prefer my 2016 specialized diverged DSW (older model) than a bike specifically made for gravel (650B, steel frame etc.) for the kind of rides I do. I just change tires when I need to. A gravel bike, although more comfortable for that 20%, would be too heavy for the other 80%.

Comment: If the budget and storage allows for it, then N+1 is the way to go.

Comment: FWIW aero spokes [are just about worthless](https://novemberbicycles.com/blogs/blog/from-the-vault-spoke-aerodynamics):  "At all AOAs, the wheel with the CX-Rays was a smidge faster, generating about 11 fewer grams of drag on average at 30mph. If you recall the [calculations from yesterday's blog](https://novemberbicycles.com/blogs/blog/the-rail-prototype-wind-tunnel-data-and-calculations.html), you'll see that 11 grams of drag at 30mph is - yep - 1 aero watt."  So paying extra for aero spokes on your wheels will save you 1 entire watt of power **if you cruise at 30 mph**. (< 1/4 watt @ 20mph)

Comment: thanks - I don't think I could 'cruise' at 30mph. The biggest factor is obviously me so shaving 300grams or some aero here and there is a bit pointless if there's a big hulk on top of the bike ;)